# httpclient: Copy HttpResponse to HttpServletResponse over https

Tags: tomcat, servlets, httpclient, httpresponse

I have the following code to convert a httpresponse to httpservletresponse, it works very well if accessing the server over http URL, but it does not work over https.

The problem is that I get empty string from the httpservletresponse if the URL is HTTPs.

```
public void extractResponse(HttpResponse httpResponse, HttpServletResponse response)
{
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    try {
        inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();


        String responseStr = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());  //Get the contect from httpresponse, it has the value I want


        copyStream(inputStream, response.getOutputStream());
    } catch (IllegalStateException | IOException e) {
    }
    finally{
        if(inputStream != null)
        {
            try {
                inputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Wrapper for IOUtils.copy
 * @param input
 * @param output
 * @throws IOException
 */
public void copyStream(InputStream input, OutputStream output) throws IOException
{
    IOUtils.copy(input, output);
}
```

FYI, I am using tomcat on both servers, and the version of httpclient is 4.13.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this figured out by myself, this issue was cause by inconsistent HTTP Schema between the two servers.

For example, if you are creating HTTP Request by using HTTPClient in server A, and the request will be sent to server B, if you are using HTTP schema (the URL will be 'http://example.com') to access server A, you have to use the same HTTP schema when you creating the HTTP request, on the other side, if you are using HTTPS in server A, you have to use HTTPS to access server B, otherwise, it will never works.

Once you confirm the consistent HTTP schema, the code I posted on my question will works.